# Custom outlook add in not opening from more apps popup

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have custom outlook add in working fine in Outlook client and browser in one Office 365 tenant. Add ins are displayed like below in browser. Please note I haven't added icon of our custom outlook add in due to privacy reasons.

[image]

However the same add in is added to another Office 365 tenant works fine in Outlook client but doesn't open in browser. One thing I noticed is the Outlook add in icons are displayed inside More apps icon and clicking on the custom add in doesn't do anything. At the same time add ins provided by Microsoft like Send to OneNote works fine.
[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to force showing the Outlook add ins icons like the first screenshot. Since Outlook add in works fine in the first tenant.

I am adding part of outlook add in xml below for reference:

```
<DesktopFormFactor>
   <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
      <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
         <Group id="msgGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip" />
            <!-- Create Button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgCreateBtn">
               <Label resid="pnlButtonLabel" />
               <Tooltip resid="paneReadButtonTooltip" />
               <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                  <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
               </Supertip>
               <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-80" />
               </Icon>
               <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="TaskPaneUrl" />
               </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- 4 more such buttons -->
         </Group>
      </OfficeTab>
   </ExtensionPoint>
</DesktopFormFactor>
```

Comment: Just to be clear this is working in the Win32 version of outlook, but NOT in Outlook Web Access?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT correct. It is working in Outlook in Windows 10 but not in Outlook Web Access in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @Sushrul Paranjape: Could you please confirm if you're using any sub-menu command in your custom outlook add-in?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have added outlook add in xml for reference. In total we have 5 button inside the add in. Let me know if any other details can help.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT It is happening to me also. Started like a week ago. More and more users are starting to report that also. I think this is something related to a browser update. More info can be found here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2760

Comment: Hey, does your add-in include a menu element? It will looks something like `<Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgComposeMenuButton">`?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we do not have menu element in our outlook add-in.

Comment: Today I tested and it is working for me. I will check with team members and confirm.

Comment: I didn't change anything but this issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> However the same add in is added to another Office 365 tenant works fine in Outlook client but doesn't open in browser

First of all, try to clear the browser cache to load the add-in. Most probably the add-in was not loaded by the web browser for any reason. See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information how to do that on different platforms.

Also you may find the [Troubleshoot development errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors) article where the most widely spread issues are described and steps for troubleshooting them.